# What browsers use their own copy of Flash?

Tags: flash, browser

I am suffering from a Flash related issue, that aside I would just like to know more about this.

I know that some browsers such as Chrome use their own copy of Flash, which they control the updates etc. for, whereas others don't.

What I would like to know is which do and don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, chrome is the only one that uses its own version.

**EDIT:**

As a commenter pointed out, Metro IE10 will also have a specific version of flash built in and will not use the installed ActiveX plugin.

Comment: +1 ... While IE uses the ActiveX plugin, the rest of the browsers use the "netscape compatible" plugin.  However, Chrome is the only browser that "maintains" it's own separate instance of the Flash Plugin. If necessary, you can install your own version of Flash with Chrome (I do this so I can use the debug Flash player). You then need to disable the built in Flash Player that Chrome uses, by going to: chrome://plugins/

Comment: Not just Chrome, Metro IE10 will also have a baked in version - though it may be a bit hobbled.

Comment: Thank you! You gave me everything that I needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

IE uses a different version of Flash (ActiveX). Chrome uses its own type of flash.

Some more info on mozilla flash if your intrested.

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keep-flash-up-to-date-and-troubleshoot-problems

Answer (score 1):

Currently just Google Chrome and Metro Internet Explorer 10 (the version of IE10 that is accessed from the windows 8 start menu).  Though MS says it will only enabled it for sites on it's compatibility view list.